# Insert new row in a table and auto id number

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I want to insert a new row in my table. I want the id to be generated right automatically and not asked from the user. The user only provides *title* and *text*. I wrote this code in PHP:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "mydb"; 
$username = "myuser"; 
$password = "mypsw";
$link = mysql_connect( $hostname , $username , $password ) or 
        die("Attention! Problem with the connection : " . mysql_error());
if (!$link) 
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_query("SET NAMES ‘utf8’",$link);
mysql_select_db("mydb", $link);
$lastid=mysql_insert_id();
$lastid=$lastid+1;
$sql="INSERT INTO announcements VALUES ('$lastid',CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[text]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) 
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($link);
header("Location: announcement.php");
?>
```

Sadly when I test it on my website, I get this error:

> Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Is `mysql_insert_id()` not working? What is wrong?

Comment: You won't have a valid mysql_insert_id() until you do an insert in the current session/connection. Workaround: AUTOINCREMENT the pk (in table create script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for last insert id and you didn't inserted anything.

1. Convert your ID field in db to be autoincrement if its not.
2. Insert into database your announcment
3. Then ask for id using mysql_insert_id to get it.

But I see that you are not using it only when inserting then you don't need that functionality anyhow. Just insert without ID like this

```
"insert into announcements (InsertDate, Title, Text) VALUES (CURDATE(), '$_POST[title]', '$_POST[text]')";
```

and you should really be careful with your queries when using values from $_POST or $_GET or any other user typed value. There is possibility to execute SQLInjection through your form fields, so I suggest you to use mysql escape command or use parameters.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to convert my id field to auto increment but I got this back: #1062 - ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Delete your ID filed from table, than add it again with the auto_increment option. This error is because you have already records in that table. But make sure that you are not using already existing ids somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this. mysql will happily create an auto_increment column for you:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
   id int not null primary key auto_increment
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---add this to your PK field
);

INSERT INTO x (id) VALUES (null); // creates id = 1
INSERT INTO x (id) VALUES (null); // creates id = 2
```

mysql_insert_id() only returns the last id created by the CURRENT connection. You haven't inserted any data yet when you first run it, so you get back nothing.

Your version is incredibly vulnerable to race conditions. There is NO guarantee that the last ID you retrieve with mysql_insert_id() will not ALSO get retrieved by another copy of the script running in parallel, and get sniped out from under this copy of the script.

Comment: Thank God for auto_increment.

Answer (score 4):

The primary key column on announcements should be auto_increment.  When you do mysql_insert_id() it retrieves the id from the last query executed from that connection.

Because the INSERT is the query you are currently performing, it errors.

Try

```
INSERT INTO announcements 
(date_field, title, text)
VALUES  (CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[text]')
```

Just replace 'date_field', 'title', and 'text' with the applicable column names.

Alternatively the following should also work, as a NULL value in the AutoIncrement value should be acceptable

```
INSERT INTO announcements VALUES (NULL,CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[text]')
```

As mentioned in the other suggestion posted, you should make sure that the primary key field of the announcements table is set to be auto_increment.

Just for completion, you would use mysql_insert_id() when you want to use the id for the row you just inserted, i.e. if you then want to select the row you just inserted you could do

```
'SELECT * FROM announcements WHERE id = '.mysql_insert_id()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is set up properly, with the `id` field as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you just need to perform an INSERT where you do not specify a value for `id`. That means you must specify the names of the columns you are inserting. So this line:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO announcements VALUES ('$lastid',CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[text]')";
```

becomes this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO announcements (`date`,`title`,`text`) VALUES (CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]','$_POST[text]')";
```

I guessed what your column names might be. Obviously they need to match your table definition.

If you do this, then the `mysql_insert_id()` function will return the `id` of the row you *just* inserted. (That is, it gives you the value of the previous insert, not the next one.)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to add "auto increment" to the table when creating it.
This will add an id automatically when inserting something.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE announcements 
(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  some_date int(11),
  title varchar(200),
  text varchar(3000) 
);
```

`mysql_insert_id` "Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query " - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php